# How to animate a Container widget in the GridView from the current index to the new index with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Flutter app, I've implemented a `GridView` widget containing 16 white containers. Each container represents a position on the grid. Now, I want to incorporate smooth animations for the player's movement across these containers. Specifically, when the player transitions from one grid index to another (e.g., from index 3 to 9), I aim to create a visually appealing animation that reflects the movement.

This is my code:

```
class PlayerGrid extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PlayerGridState createState() => _PlayerGridState();
}

class _PlayerGridState extends State<PlayerGrid> {
  int currentPosition = 3;
  int newPosition = 9;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 250,
      width: 250,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      color: Colors.green.shade900,
      child: GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 4, crossAxisSpacing: 0, mainAxisSpacing: 0),
        itemCount: 16,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Center(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                AnimatedPositioned(
                  duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                  curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                  child: Grid(
                    isPlayerHere: index == newPosition,
                    index: index,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Grid extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isPlayerHere;
  final int index;
  const Grid({required this.isPlayerHere, required this.index});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
          child: isPlayerHere
              ? Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/user.png',
                  height: 30,
                  color: Colors.red.shade900,
                )
              : Text(index.toString())),
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKLqX.png)

Comment: Usually this kind of custom thing uses https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html. But if you want to use the gridview widget, I would start by separating the player image from the cell. You could for example use a stack, where you first draw the grid and after that you draw the player top of the grid

Comment: I applied the stack widget as you said but I couldn't make the animation of the player's movement from one index to another index